# This site crashes every single browser on my PC

Tags: windows-10, browser

I'm trying to access this site, and it crashes every single browser that I've tested: Chrome, Brave, Edge, and Opera.

```
plotly.com/python/plotly-express
```

Windows 10 Pro (22H2 19045.3930).

Someone can explain why?

Comment: What means "crashes" exactly ?

Comment: They're sending the whole lot at you in one go, rather than lazy loading. It loads for me - eventually - but there are times I thought it wouldn't get there. The page is about 500MB once it does load; maybe you're pushed for memory.

Comment: It just loads fine for me in Firefox and Chrome on Win11.

Comment: Probably memory / ressources issue.

Comment: Is your PC being forced to use virtual memory to load a large page? Try adjusting the size of VM, either making it larger **or** smaller, to see if it helps: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-virtual-memory-size-windows-10 . Set initial and max to same size to reduce disk fragmentation, and note that VM may be 1,000x slower than RAM, so avoid excessive use, if possible.

Comment: Not here (Kali VM 3 GB of memory).  Make sure you have not assigned more than 1/2 your host resources to the VM.

Comment: Works fine on Safari on iOS.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'll accept as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likelihood is you're struggling for memory, paging to disk, or even that your line is taking its sweet time to get the data to you. The page is horribly heavy & is not loaded in a sensible manner.

They're sending the whole lot at you in one go, rather than lazy loading [like such as Facebook does, so you don't get the whole thing until you scroll to it, it comes in usable chunks].
It loads for me - eventually after about 2 or 3 minutes, with a lot of 'spinning wheel' cursor, which on a machine with a 350mbps line & 64GB RAM makes it 'not my fault' - but there were times I thought it wouldn't get there.
The page is about 500MB once it does load.